# Token StartElement in state Epilog would result in an invalid XML document

Tags: c#, xml, xmltextwriter

I am getting the error "Token StartElement in state Epilog would result in an invalid XML document." when i get the data from datatable and try to convery it to xml file .

Code :

```
DataTable dtTest = new DataTable();
dtTest.Columns.Add("Name");
dtTest.Columns.Add("NickName");
dtTest.Columns.Add("Code");
dtTest.Columns.Add("reference");

dtTest.Rows.Add("Yash", "POPs", "Vapi", "None1");
dtTest.Rows.Add("shilpa", "shilpa", "valsad", "None2");
dtTest.Rows.Add("Dinesh", "dinu", "pune", "None3");
dtTest.Rows.Add("rahul", "mady", "pardi", "None4");
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();

StringWriter stringwriter = new StringWriter();

XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringwriter);
xmlTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
xmlTextWriter.WriteStartDocument();
foreach (var row in dtTest.AsEnumerable())
{
        xmlTextWriter.WriteStartElement("");
        xmlTextWriter.WriteAttributeString("orderid", row.Field<string>("Name"));
        xmlTextWriter.WriteElementString("type",  row.Field<string>("Name"));
        xmlTextWriter.WriteElementString("status", row.Field<string>("Name"));
        xmlTextWriter.WriteElementString("productno", row.Field<string>("Name"));
        xmlTextWriter.WriteEndElement();
}
XmlDocument docSave = new XmlDocument();
docSave.LoadXml(stringwriter.ToString());
```

What is the cause of this error, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65460359/create-xml-by-convert-two-datatable-row-to-one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems here:

1. You are writing multiple root elements to your document, one for each call to `xmlTextWriter.WriteStartElement("")`.  However, a well-formed XML document must have one and only one [root element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element), so you need to wrap your row elements in some container element.

   (You might have been thinking that [`WriteStartDocument()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter.writestartdocument?view=net-5.0) would write the root element, but it does not.  It just writes the XML declaration.)
2. You are using `XmlTextWriter` but this class is deprecated.  From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmltextwriter?view=net-5.0):

   > Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, we recommend that you create [XmlWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter?view=net-5.0) instances by using the XmlWriter.Create method and the XmlWriterSettings class to take advantage of new functionality.

   If you switch to `XmlWriter` you will get clearer error messages and better error checking.
3. You are trying to write elements with **no name**:

   ```
   xmlTextWriter.WriteStartElement("");
   ```

   This would result in malformed XML. `XmlTextWriter` seems not to check for this, but `XmlWriter` does.

Putting all of the above together, your code can be modified as follows:

```
var stringwriter = new StringWriter();
using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringwriter, new XmlWriterSettings {  Indent = true }))
{
    xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();
    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Root");
    foreach (var row in dtTest.AsEnumerable())
    {
        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Row");
        xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("orderid", row.Field<string>("Name"));
        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("type",  row.Field<string>("Name"));
        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("status", row.Field<string>("Name"));
        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("productno", row.Field<string>("Name"));
        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
    }
    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
}
var xml = stringwriter.ToString();
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cbC6oy).

Comment: thanks a lot bro. i understood the concept .really appreciate your help and support here