# create xml by convert two datatable row to one

Tags: c#, xml

I have order table and order line table . if there are 2 item for a  order then there will be 2 line will return by inner join . in this time i need to convert it as one xml file rather than 2 xml file

i give the code example blow :

```
DataTable dtTest = new DataTable();
dtTest.Columns.Add("Name");
dtTest.Columns.Add("NickName");
dtTest.Columns.Add("Code");
dtTest.Columns.Add("reference");

//here Yash is a common name to 2 row .
dtTest.Rows.Add("Yash", "POPs", "Vapi", "None1");
dtTest.Rows.Add("Yash", "POPs", "Vapi", "None2");
dtTest.Rows.Add("Dinesh", "dinu", "pune", "None3");
dtTest.Rows.Add("rahul", "mady", "pardi", "None4");
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();

StringWriter stringwriter = new StringWriter();

XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringwriter);
xmlTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
xmlTextWriter.WriteStartDocument();
foreach (var row in dtTest.AsEnumerable())
{
      xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Row");
                xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Name", row.Field<string>("Name"));
                xmlWriter.WriteElementString("NickName", row.Field<string>("NickName"));
                xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Code", row.Field<string>("Code"));
                //if there are two common name then i need to write both  reference for the name in same file  
                xmlWriter.WriteElementString("reference", row.Field<string>("reference"));
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
}
XmlDocument docSave = new XmlDocument();
docSave.LoadXml(stringwriter.ToString());
```

Current output :

```
{<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Root>
  <Row Name="Yash">
    <NickName>POPs</NickName>
    <Code>Vapi</Code>
    <reference>None1</reference>
  </Row>
  <Row Name="Yash">
    <NickName>POPs</NickName>
    <Code>Vapi</Code>
    <reference>None2</reference>
  </Row>
  <Row Name="Dinesh">
    <NickName>dinu</NickName>
    <Code>pune</Code>
    <reference>None3</reference>
  </Row>
  <Row Name="rahul">
    <NickName>mady</NickName>
    <Code>pardi</Code>
    <reference>None4</reference>
  </Row>
</Root>}
```

Expected output :

```
{<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Root>
  <Row Name="Yash">
    <NickName>POPs</NickName>
    <Code>Vapi</Code>
    <reference>None1</reference>
     <reference>None2</reference>
  </Row>
  <Row Name="Dinesh">
    <NickName>dinu</NickName>
    <Code>pune</Code>
    <reference>None3</reference>
  </Row>
  <Row Name="rahul">
    <NickName>mady</NickName>
    <Code>pardi</Code>
    <reference>None4</reference>
  </Row>
</Root>}
```

could you please help me on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a GroupBy :

```
            var groups = dtTest.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => new { Name = x.Field<string>("Name"), NickName = x.Field<string>("NickName"), Code = x.Field<string>("Code") });
            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                xmlTextWriter.WriteStartElement("Row");
                xmlTextWriter.WriteAttributeString("Name", group.Key.Name);
                xmlTextWriter.WriteElementString("NickName", group.Key.NickName);
                xmlTextWriter.WriteElementString("Code", group.Key.Code);
                foreach (DataRow row in group)
                {
                    xmlTextWriter.WriteElementString("reference", row.Field<string>("reference"));
                }
                xmlTextWriter.WriteEndElement();
            }
            XmlDocument docSave = new XmlDocument();
            docSave.LoadXml(stringwriter.ToString());
        }
```